# How to check passowrd in laravel databse for other site imported users

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have one site which is working fine !

Now I need to convert that site in laravel so I  import all that records in laravel but how can I logged that user in laravel .

this is my old site password

```
$2y$10$3RFMhygrniJuA9lglZWd7OD.dARjkqQXu0H7eLX7PGYl9JIW9rvHO,
```

Now when I am trying to login it does not allow me to login .

I have total 10K records ,How can I overcome from this?

can anyone please help me ?

Comment: How does your old site hash users' password? just use the same hash method in laravel

Comment: Is your password correct if you don't know try to change it with `mysql code UPDATE user SET password = PASSWORD("newpassword");` example if this is not the case is it about the verification so go on and check [Hash::Check](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
login.blade.php


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Login Form</h3>  

{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('UserName') !!}
    {!! Form::text('username', null,
        array(
              'class'=>'form-control',
              'placeholder'=>'Your UserName')) !!}
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('password') !!}
    {!! Form::text('password', null,
        array(
              'class'=>'form-control',
              'placeholder'=>'Your Password')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Login',
      array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```